# How to read all data from a TCP socket server and execute an operation afterwards

Tags: sockets, go

After spending many hours on this. I can't find a way to read all the data coming from a TCP socket server and then make an operation, as I can't find a way to break the loop.

The socket server sends texts containing a lot of lines finishing with "\n". The client should be able to read all those lines and make a POST request with all the data but the loop always hangs out and there is not a way to break it. Then, it will continue waiting for more data, so a stop condition could be a three seconds timeout.

I have tried different solutions (Scanner, ReadString, ReadLine, ReadAll) but it always hangs out and the loop won't ever finish.

The last line in the code is never printed.

```
 conn, err := net.Dial("tcp", "127.0.0.1:15000")
 reader := bufio.NewReader(conn)
 message := ""
 for {
     line, err := reader.ReadString('\n')
     if err == io.EOF {
         break
     }
     message += line
 }
 log.Println(message)
```

Comment: Unless the server closes the connection after it has sent all the lines, you will never have an io.EOF error. The ReadString will always block and wait for more data. To do what you want to do, the server should close the connection when all the lines are sent, or you need a special line to be send when done to inform the client  that there are no more lines after this one.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't modify the server. I am thinking of using goroutine, channel and select.

Comment: You need a criteria to determine when the server has finished sending lines. It could be the number of lines, a delay with no lines sent, etc. Without this criteria, select and goroutines won't help.

Comment: Once I read the first line a timeout of 3 seconds

Comment: why you don't do your operations in the meantime while you'r  reading ? or what is the operation type ?

Comment: Using a timeout to denote end-of-data is not a good idda, due to the possibility of network lags. Unless it is a REALLY BIG timeout, 3 seconds is not going to cut it.

Comment: For this particular problem is more than enough.

Answer (score 1):

If your only option is to read lines until a timeout, you can set a read deadline on the connection after the first read completes. You can then intercept the timeout error, and convert it to an EOF for the buffered reader to correctly interpret your intent.

```
type timeoutReader struct {
    net.Conn
    once sync.Once
}

func (r *timeoutReader) Read(b []byte) (int, error) {
    n, err := r.Conn.Read(b)

    // Set a read deadline only after the first Read completes
    r.once.Do(func() {
        r.Conn.SetReadDeadline(time.Now().Add(3 * time.Second))
    })

    // If we got a timeout, treat it as an io.EOF so the bufio.Scanner handles
    // the error as if it was the normal end of the stream.
    var netErr net.Error
    if errors.As(err, &netErr) && netErr.Timeout() {
        return n, io.EOF
    }
    return n, err
}

func main() {
    conn, err := net.Dial("tcp", "127.0.0.1:15000")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(&timeoutReader{Conn: conn})
    message := ""
    for scanner.Scan() {
        message += scanner.Text()
    }
    if err := scanner.Err(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    log.Println(message)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the criteria is a timeout of 3 seconds after the first line is received, the solution is to close the socket 3 seconds after the first line is received.

```
var firstLineReceived bool
conn, err := net.Dial("tcp", "127.0.0.1:15000")
reader := bufio.NewReader(conn)
message := ""
for {
    line, err := reader.ReadString('\n')
    if err == io.EOF {
        break
    }
    message += line
    if !firstLineReceived {
        firstLineReceived = true
        go func(){
            time.Sleep(3*time.Second)
            conn.Close()
        }()
    }
}
log.Println(message)
```

Comment: Wouldn't using a timeout on the Read itself be more appropriate for a timeout?

Comment: @JimB not sure it is a read timeout. The OP said 3 seconds after the first line is received. Some more lines could be received after the first line, in which case a read timeout would not have the same behavior

Comment: Network operations use a deadline, so `SetReadDeadline(time.Now().Add(3*time.Second))` will stop reading after 3 seconds. Then you cold also differentiate between EOF, unexpected close, and Timeout.

Comment: You get a timeout error (note that your example will go into an infinite loop, because closing a connection on a read returns `use of closed network connection`, not `io.EOF`)

Comment: This worked, although the below answer is more completed, but it would need a for loop to continue reading more texts.