# How can I send multiple messages to a socket net.Conn in Golang?

Tags: go, sockets, tcp

I'm trying to implement socket communication between a Golang server and an Android Kotlin app. Right now, I'm trying to use the built-in `net` library to implement the socket server on Golang. Here's what my code looks like:

```
import (
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net"
    "os"
)

var (
    SOCKET_PORT   = flag.Int("socket_server_port", 9001, "Socket sckServer port")
    HOST          = flag.String("host name", "localhost", "server host name")
    socketConnArr = make(map[string]net.Conn)
)

func StartSocket() {
    listen, err := net.Listen(TYPE, fmt.Sprintf(":%d", *SOCKET_PORT))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("conn err: %s", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    defer listen.Close()

    fmt.Printf("Socket sckServer serving at localhost:%d...\n", *SOCKET_PORT)

    for {
        conn, err := listen.Accept()
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("accept err: %s", err)
            continue
        }
        socketConnArr[fmt.Sprintf(":%d", *SOCKET_PORT)] = conn

        fmt.Printf("socket client from: %s\n", conn.RemoteAddr().String())

        go connWrite(conn, "socket server ack")
        // go connRead(conn)
    }
}

func SockWrite(message string) {
    for _, val := range socketConnArr {
        go connWrite(val, message)
    }
}

func SockRead(){
    for _, val := range socketConnArr {
        go connRead(val)
    }
}

func connRead(conn net.Conn) {
    fmt.Println("Reading")
    buffer := make([]byte, 1024)
    bytesRead, err := conn.Read(buffer)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("req err: %s", err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("Read %d bytes: %s", bytesRead, string(buffer[:bytesRead]))

    err = conn.Close()

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("connRead close err: %s", err)
    }
}

func connWrite(conn net.Conn, message string) {
    fmt.Println("Sending")
    conn.Write([]byte("\n")) //for some reason, this is very important
    conn.Write([]byte(message))
}

func GetConnList() map[string]net.Conn {
    return socketConnArr
}
```

And here's what the Android Kotlin code looks like:

```
lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
    var response = ""

    try {
        socket = Socket(SERVER_IP, SERVER_PORT)
        writer = PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream())
        reader = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()))

        // Send the message to the server
        writer.println(socketInitMsg)
        writer.flush()

        Log.i(SocketHelper.TAG, "socket conn while: ${socket.isConnected}")
        while (true) {
            if (reader.readLine() != null) {
                response = reader.readLine()
                Log.i(SocketHelper.TAG, "response: $response")
            }
        }
        Log.i(SocketHelper.TAG, "socket conn wend: ${socket.isConnected}")
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        Log.e(SocketHelper.TAG, "err1: " + e.localizedMessage)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Log.e(SocketHelper.TAG, "err11: " + e.localizedMessage)
    }
}
```

After some testing, it seems like any `Write()` and/or `Read()` won't succeed when `Close()` isn't called, which is the weirdest behavior that I've ever experienced. With that in mind, now I have quite a dilemma. How can I reuse the `net.Conn`s when I have to close them in every operation I need to do? I needed to pass messages to the client whenever a certain condition is hit, and there are times the android app would send some "request" to the server as well. Each side might not need to do a `.Write()` for a long period of time. I created a map with the `conn.RemoteAddr()` as the key and conn itself as the value hoping that there was a way to somehow "restart" those connections, but `net.Conn` doesn't seem to have a way to start connections.

Comment: I'd start by sending another `\n` after writing the message (because `readLine` will be waiting for that).  A TCP connection is just a stream of data - you need to decide how to split it into messages. Your Kotlin code looks like its using `\n` as a delimiter so you will need to do the same in Go.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. If I send that additional `\n`, does that mean I won't need to `Close()` the connection? How about the reading part? What additional steps do I need so I don't need another `Close()` call? Yeah, from my test, it does seem that android is sending the extra `\n` that's why I thought that's the case with Golang as well.

Comment: Sending a newline is important if you are using newlines to delimit messages. TCP is a stream, there are no "messages" at that level of the protocol, it is up to you to frame them correctly.

Comment: Ref the "reading part" - [`bufio.Scanner`](https://pkg.go.dev/bufio#Scanner) would help (see the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60969067/11810946)). The only reason you are having to call `Close` is that one end is waiting for a `\n` or the connection to close (so sending the `\n` should resolve this). `if (reader.readLine() != null)` is another issue as this effectively ignores a message...

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to the comments by @JimB and @Brits, I found out that I just need to tell `socket` that I'm done writing to it at the moment and everything worked flawlessly.

Comment: I'd suggest rephrasing that to "tell the other end of the connection that the message is complete" (the `\n` is just like any other character to the TCP library; it's your code listening at the other end that assigns it meaning).

Comment: Eh, I don't see any difference between that phrase and the one I made. It's the same phrase.

Comment: My aim was to make it clear that all you are doing is sending another byte (i.e. `\n`) over the TCP stream. Saying "tell socket" could be interpreted to mean you are doing something out of band (the TCP stack on your PC does something special when you do the additional send), which is not the case.